# How can I view an X Window from a remote system on their local system?

Tags: xorg, remote-access

What shall I do to show my remote x window on my local system?

From the local system: `export DISPLAY=local:0.0`
OR

From the remote system: `export DISPLAY=local:0.0`
OR

From the local system: `export DISPLAY=remote:0.0`
OR

From the remote system: `export DISPLAY=remote:0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export DISPLAY=local:0.0`  should be the right answer. You could just test it to see the result

Answer (score 4):

X clients (e.g. the remote application) find the X server (e.g. your local system) via the `$DISPLAY` environment variable, and are authenticated for connection via [xauth cookies](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xauth.html).

You must either allow a direct connection from the remote system to the local system and set `$DISPLAY` appropriately (e.g. `export DISPLAY=1.2.3.4:0` or `DISPLAY=1.2.3.4:0 xclock`) and propagate the cookie to the remote system, or use something like SSH's X forwarding (i.e. `ssh -X user@remotehost xclock`) in order to automatically allow them to display on your system.

Comment: Where i write the command export DISPLAY? from remote or from local and 1.2.3.4 is ip of the remote or the local? there are many odds for that iw ill edit my quest and enter the odds that ive gotten from your answer

Answer (score 0):

just go and install `xrdp` and `x11rdp` on the destination host then connect using remmina or any other remote client and choose for connection the `(console)`